# Is there a performance different between compiling and linking mkl library via icc or gcc?

Tags: gcc, compilation, intel, icc

I cant find any info about this topic,
Is there a different in runtime performance when running a program which was compiled and linked with gcc or icc ?

(My assumption is that the program run on Intel architecture)

Comment: Do you mean an Intel **micro**architecture?  i.e. a CPU actually designed by Intel, rather than an x86 CPU designed by AMD, VIA, or other.  MKL only runs on three architectures:  x86 (32bit, aka Intel Architecture (IA-32)), AMD64 (aka x86-64 aka intel64), and IA-64.  So all of them could be called Intel architectures if you buy into Intel's naming scheme for AMD64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both compilers are officially supported by MKL and they link the same libraries such as `libmkl_core.a` or `libmkl_core.so`, which do the actual work for MKL. The performance of MKL operations should be same. But of course the code written by yourself could be different as they are compiled by different compilers.

**Edit**

MKL is designed as a C library. Most of the APIs are pre-compiled and designed to run on large input data, which expect a relatively long running time. The way you calling the API won't affect the performance very much.

There are inline code and helper marcos through. For example `mkl_direct_call.h` include inline code/marco for small matrix multiplication, small matrix (size of ~20 or smaller) may get performance improvement with this code. So you may see performance difference when involving this part. Please refer to the following links for more details.

[Improve Intel MKL Performance for Small Problems: The Use of MKL_DIRECT_CALL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/improve-intel-mkl-performance-for-small-problems-the-use-of-mkl-direct-call)

[Limitations of the Direct Call](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/528556)

Comment: So MKL doesn't include much if any template / inline stuff?  Just pre-compiled code with prototypes / declarations in headers?

Comment: @PeterCordes Great comment. MKL is designed as a C library. So the API is relatively simple. There may be inline code through. It should be easy to check the header files for this part.